# Getting WMS layer data using OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers, wms, getfeatureinfo, url, albania

I want to fetch WMS data but not for one feature. I want all the data fetched. I want all the table of attributes of the shapefile itself.

```js
const municipalitiesLocal = new TileLayer({
  source: new TileWMS({
    url: "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/my_workspace1/wms",
    params: {
      LAYERS: "my_workspace1:adm_boundary",
      VERSION: "1.1.0",
    },
  }),
  visible: true,
  title: "Bashkite Local",
  information: "Kufiri i tokësor i republikës së Shqipërisë",
  displayInLayerSwitcher: true,
});
```

`getFeatureInfoUrl()` cannot fulfill my requirements.

Comment: Then set up WFS service on your Geoserver.

Comment: I want to create a select control form. First to choose the layer name. Then one of its columns and than the unique data of that column. I need access to table of database. Can you help me more how to proceed with WFS ?

Comment: Sorry, Geoserver is not my area.

Comment: WMS isn't a tile service, so you wouldn't be able to get any tile data from it/one.  A WMS doesn't provide any features or data, only an image representation of them.

Comment: You can get all the feature types from a WFS by making a GetCapabilities request.  If you already have a WMS set up with a shapefile datasource then you just need to enable the WFS, no need for anything else.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I used WMF service to get the data but I want WMS to render the layers in the application. Thus my app is a bit heavy. WFS as vector Layer allows to fetch the data and do further manipulation. Maybe I'll try the app deployed on server and later decide. Thanks a lot